# get n latest arguments shell script

Tags: bash, shell

So I have some script

```
files="${!#}"
if [[ -n "$files" ]]
then
        do some instructions
else
        do some instructions
fi
```

I really need to how to get n arguments from the 7th argument or N argument.
Something like this:

```
var1=arg1 arg2 arg3 .... arg7 argN argN+1 ...
```

Capture them in a variable like this:

```
var1= argN argN+1 ....
```

Comment: I hate to ask, but I've never run into it. What is `"${!#}"` doing? Forgive me if this is a common thing.

Comment: `$#` is the number of arguments, so it's using the value of `$#` as the name of the variable to expand, i.e., `${!#}` expands to the value of the *last* argument.

Comment: Use substring expansion to get a specific subsequence of postitional arguments (e.g., `"${@:7}"`). What you want to do with them will dictate how you should use the expansion. `var1="${@:7}"` is likely *not* what you want (since that will erase the distinction between arguments that `@` is supposed to preserve). Maybe `var1=( "${@:7}" )`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a bash array and then slice it:

<sup>**As @GordonDavisson pointed out, you can directly slice `$@`**</sup>

```sh
#!/bin/bash

files=( "${@:7}" )

# show content of the array
declare -p files
```

Comment: You don't even need to store the args in an array first, you can slice the arg list directly: `"${@:6}"` will get the args starting with the sixth (`$6`), and `"${@:$#-3}"` will get the last 4 arguments (because `$#` is the number of arguments).

Comment: Oh, thanks; I forgot that you could slice `$@`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me mostly though i did it in one line but your solution worked.

Answer (score 3):

Use `shift` to remove the first `N-1` arguments, then `$@` will contain the remaining arguments.

```
shift 6
if [ $# -ne 0 ]
then
    files=("$@")
    # do something with $files
else
    # do something else
fi
```